# after_initialize causes stack overflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stack-overflow

Attempting to be DRY, I'm trying to assign to a model's instance variable after object initialization.

```
class WorkNote < ActiveRecord::Base

  def after_initialize
    self[:clockin]= WorkNote.last_clockout
  end

  def self.last_clockout
    WorkNote.find(:first, :order => "clockout DESC").clockout
  end
end
```

However, the method call in `after_initialize` causes a `SystemStackError`:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SystemStackError: stack level too deep: SELECT * FROM "work_notes"  ORDER BY clockout DESC LIMIT 1
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:212:in `log'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:157:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:402:in `catch_schema_changes'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:157:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:305:in `select'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all_without_query_cache'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:62:in `select_all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:661:in `find_by_sql'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1553:in `find_every'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1510:in `find_initial'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:613:in `find'
    from /Users/noob/jobs/app/models/work_note.rb:10:in `last_clockout'
    from /Users/noob/jobs/app/models/work_note.rb:6:in `after_initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:347:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:347:in `callback'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1662:in `send'
... 5116 levels...
```

If I comment out `after_initialize`, the `last_clockout` method has no problems.  Neither does this happen when I use a callback like `before_save` instead of `after_initialize`.  Why is `after_initialize` causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

After initialize is called whenever an object is instantiated (new'ed). Your find call in self.last_clockout is creating an object, and then recursively calling the after_initialize. Hence the infinite recursion and stack overflow.

`Before_save` or `after_create` are more appropriate.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 1):

I've found [default_value_for](http://blog.phusion.nl/2008/10/03/47/) is a very good way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful replies!  I get what the problem is.  Wouldn't `default_value_for` have the same problem, though?  Seems like as long as the initial value for the attribute requires a find(), a new WorkNote object will have to be instantiated and the loop will keep happening.

Other ways I can think to do this:
a. assign the initial value in the controller, although that's not where it belongs
b. store the default value in another model, like Users

Any other suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: default_value_for works by overriding the getter and providing a default value only if it doesn't already have one. It doesn't actually change the value in the database or underlying object. Since default_value_for doesn't automatically run when the object is created (only when the column is accessed), there's no way for a use like in the original question to recurse.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to check if the initialized object is new or not, e.g.:

```
def after_initialize
  return unless self.new_record?
  self.clockin = WorkNote.last_clockout
end
```